# Rendering templates using Jinja2 and Webapp2

Tags: jquery, jinja2, webapp2

am very new to programming and apologize in advance if I do a poor job of explaining myself.

I am creating a GAE application using Python, Webapp2, Jinja2, and jquery. I can update HTML pages by passing string queries via HTML forms, adding the queries to Python dictionaries, and using Jinja2 and Webapp2 to render them and write them out.

However, when I try using the jquery Ajax post method to make a POST request instead of using the HTML form, my HTML page isn't updating. I am definitely calling the render function from my Python program but it doesn't do anything.

Any help or advice that anyone could offer me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my python code that inherits a base class that handles all of the Webapp2 requests. This normally works well.

```
class EditJobPage(AppHandler):
global objectDict
objectDict ={}

def get(self):
    jobs = Job.querynewjobs()
    TemplateDict = {}
    TemplateDict = {
        'jobs': jobs,
    }
    self.render('editjob.html', **TemplateDict)

def post(self):
    MyKey = self.request.get('job_key')
    TemplateDict = {}
    try:
        job = GetFromSafeKey(MyKey)
        objectDict['job'] = job
        TemplateDict = {
            'job': job,
        }
        if self.request.get('what') == 'rename':
            TemplateDict['jobdescription'] = self.request.get('rename_description')
            self.rename(**TemplateDict)
        elif self.request.get('what') == 'delete':
            self.delete(**TemplateDict)
        elif self.request.get('what') == 'renumber':
            TemplateDict['jobnumber'] = int(self.request.get('renumber_description'))
            self.renumber(**TemplateDict)
    except:
        TemplateDict['error'] = 'No job selected'
    self.render('editjob.html', **TemplateDict)
    logging.info('here')
```

Here is the base class. Again, this all works great when I'm calling using an HTML form button.

```
$("#deletejobbutton").click(function(event) {
var JobKey = $('#mykey').val();
var querystring = 'what=delete'
$.ajax({
url: '/templates/editjob',
data: { 
    "what": 'delete',
    "job_key": JobKey,
},
dataType: 'json',
type: "POST",
success: function(response) {
},
error: function(xhr) {
}
});
});
```

When I run this, nothing happens with the HTML page. Yet, the GAE log shows 'here', so I know that it made it to the Python code. If I try the same thing using an HTML form with string queries, however, the page updates. Here's the GAE log:

```
INFO     2014-10-27 11:39:53,404 module.py:659] default: "POST /templates/editjob HTTP/1.1" 200 2228
INFO     2014-10-27 19:40:03,249 MyClasses.py:120] here

INFO     2014-10-27 11:40:03,250 module.py:659] default: "POST /templates/editjob HTTP/1.1" 200 2228
```

Thanks again for any help. I hope this wasn't too confusing. I started from scratch a couple weeks ago so I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: I suggest you download Fiddler and see exactly what requests and responses are being generated. It will save you a lot of debugging hassle! :-) Also, use your browser's dev-tools console to look for any errors (e.g. ctrl+shift+j in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Cameron. I'll try that right away.

Answer (score 0):

How, I'm not sure. Yet, it is working fine now. I think that the jquery code wasn't actually making it down to the $.ajax function after all, although I'm not sure how it was making it to my Python script. I think that's what threw me off. I've never used jquery until today so I think I'm just trying to learn this stuff faster than I'm able to.